# Upgrading OpenSSL results in compiler error with sk_X509_pop_free

Tags: c++, openssl

When I updgraded OpenSSL from 0.9.8 to 1.0.0E I now get a compiler error. The following is a simplified version:

```
1: #include <openssl/pem.h>  
2:
3: int main( int argc, char* argv[] )  
4: {  
5:   STACK_OF(X509)* certs = NULL;  
6:   sk_X509_pop_free(certs, X509_free);
7: }
```

I get the following error:

```
CC -g0 -I/openssl/ssl/include main.cc -o main -L/openssl/ssl/lib -lcrypto -lssl
"main.cc", line 6: Error: Different types for "?:" (extern "C" void(*)(x509_st*) and void(*)(x509_st*)).
"main.cc", line 6: Warning (Anachronism): Formal argument func of type extern "C" void(*)(void*) in call to sk_pop_free(stack_st*, extern "C" void(*)(void*)) is being passed void(*)(void*).
```

Binary: ELF 32-bit MSB executable SPARC32PLUS Version 1, V8+ Required, dynamically linked, not stripped.
Compiler: CC: Sun C++ 5.9 SunOS_sparc 2007/05/03.
Operating System: Solaris 10

Comment: Please try with explicit typecast.

Comment: Thanks @dbasic. The explicit cast removed the error and left just the warning. The program runs. I have not verified that the memory is freed.

Comment: Hi, Can you please mentioned to typcasting you did and final executable code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code removes the error:

```
sk_X509_pop_free(certs, (void(*)(x509_st*))X509_free);
```